# Alternatives To Leopard Flower

Tags: networking, 13.10, windows-8

On Windows I usually setup my firewall to block all network access to programs I don't feel need internet access. The only similar program I've been able to find for Ubuntu is Leopard Flower, but it seems to be a rather unheard of project and so I'm hesitant to start using it, and I'm wondering if there is perhaps something more common that has similar features. I would like to be able to block operating system components, and regular software from accessing the network (send/receive), as well as block individual ips on a per program basis.

Answer (score 0):

iptables is the low-level tool for manipulating how the kernel deals with network access, but it is rather complicated to use directly. So there are wrapper programs such as ufw:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

which make the task of setting up firewall rules somewhat easier.

There is a GUI for ufw as well:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw

Having different rules for specific programs would be more complicated.